# Schedule AWS EC2 Windows server restart

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a way to setup a restart of a windows server on AWS at certain times or days?
For example, every saturday at 3:00 do a full restart of the server.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can schedule your instance for a stop/start.

Please refer: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/